# Strange flickering on external HDMI screen

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi

I got new laptop Hp, configuration:
i5-1250u(12h gen)
intel iRISx graphics

I use 2 OS on my laptop, Windows and Ubuntu, and when i connect my second screen on Windows everything works fine, but when i load Ubuntu thing are going wrong and it is impossible to use second screen, you can see photo below. But when i am on my Ubuntu and join projector by HDMI everything works fine.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvR7K.jpg)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmNCY.jpg)